# LINQ query issue regarding Date

Tags: c#, linq

I want to list out all records where `CloseDate` is greater than `DateTime.Now`.

I have write a query for that but it doesn't fetch records where `CloseDate` is greater than `DateTime.Now`.
See my query below

```
 var query = (from x in objEntity.VacancyMsts
                     join o in objEntity.OrganizationMst on 
                     x.OrganizationID equals o.OrganizationId into vacorg
                     from o in vacorg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where x.Status == true && x.CloseDate >= DateTime.Now
                     select new VacancyMstDTO
                     {});
```

Is there any problem in my query?

Comment: What SQL is executed against the database?

Comment: it returns recots .. my sql query is SELECT     dbo.VacancyMst.PositionTitle, dbo.VacancyMst.Description, dbo.VacancyMst.PositionLocation, dbo.OrganizationMst.OrganizationName, 
                      dbo.VacancyMst.CloseDate
FROM         dbo.VacancyMst LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.OrganizationMst ON dbo.VacancyMst.OrganizationID = dbo.OrganizationMst.OrganizationId
WHERE     (dbo.VacancyMst.Status = 1) AND (dbo.VacancyMst.CloseDate >= GETDATE())

Comment: @Manatherin yes two records are there

Comment: in the `select new VacancyMstDTO {}` do you put something inside the braces?

Comment: yes of course.. put some feilds :)

Comment: @habibzare I had put some fields in select too,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to join here if you have a FK relationship

```
var query = from x in objEntity.VacancyMsts
            where x.Status && x.CloseDate >= DateTime.Now
            select new VacancyMstDTO
            {
                OrganizationName = x.OrganizationMst.Name,
                ...
            };
```

But **I wonder** if you really want the `CloseDate` to be ahead of today, normally a close date happens in the past, no?

And, **careful** with timezones as well. I tend to always insert/update the database with `DateTime.UtcNow` and when reading, apply the user timezone...